# Pandas | Merge Row in same multiple same column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here is the example data set
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjCbr.png)

I have sorted the data set by id and update date, I want to merge the rows with same id, if one row with empty value, fill the other one with same id, if confilct, use the latest one. For rows with no duplicate id leave the empty cell as it is.

the output should be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVWJS.png)